# consume .NET WS/SOAP two servers with same structure but different methods name

Tags: .net, soap, .net-assembly, ws

I'm connecting to two SAP WS/SOAP that have the same structure (same input, same output) but different endpoints and method names.

I've imported both WS's descriptors as web reference and now I'm using them with something like this:

```
        bool pBG = true;

        sapWSBG.ZbgPogon inputBG = new sapWSBG.ZbgPogon();
        sapWSBG.ZbgPogonResponse responseBG = new sapWSBG.ZbgPogonResponse();

        sapWSRO.ZroPogon inputRO = new sapWSRO.ZroPogon();
        sapWSRO.ZroPogonResponse responseRO = new sapWSRO.ZroPogonResponse();

        if (pBG)
        {
            //set input params
            inputBG.IntHeader = getHeader((string)pPlant);
            inputBG.Pogon = (String)pPlant;
            LogXml(inputBG, "input");

            //make the call
            responseBG = clientBG.ZbgPogon(inputBG);
            LogXml(responseBG, "response");
        }
        else
        {
            //set input params
            inputRO.IntHeader = getHeader((string)pPlant);
            inputRO.Pogon = (String)pPlant;
            LogXml(inputRO, "input");

            //make the call
            responseRO = clientRO.ZroPogon(inputRO);
            LogXml(responseRO, "response");
        }

        //process data in response(s)
        ...
```

In order not to build two separate assemblies, and avoid duplicating same code, is there any way to make only the request to each server but keeping the rest of the code the same?

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is solution for this by using dynamic type.
Unfortunately, SQL assemblies can't use this with the limited libraries the SQL engine has